# Opening application from another application while being able to interact with it's code

Tags: c#, wpf

So I'm trying to create a Launcher for 3 different WPF apps, the idea is that you only have to log in once but then you can load data for any of the 3 via the launcher then when youve selected the data you want it'll launch that app.

Had no issues up until I tried to do open the mainwindow for the apps, the xaml rejects all resources for that app and instead tries to load them from the launcher which they don't exist in.

Basically when a piece of data is selected it currently does:

```
Window window = new Window(); //This is the window from the second project
window.vars = this.data; //I need to be able to set variables within the second project
```

But when I do this all my static resources break, how can I open the second WPF project from the first one while forcing it to use it's own app.xaml and not the one for the launcher?

Comment: If these are different applications, you'll need some kind of interprocess communication for the desired interaction. Why don't you simply have three library projects that are linked into your launcher application?

Comment: Is the overall goal to let users either open the required individual app themselves, or if they want launch it from the launcher? Otherwise I'm not sure why they are not just all in one app?

Comment: The 3 apps are existing fully built WPF apps, would be too difficult to rewrite them to just be libraries

Comment: @Digitalsa1nt It started as just one project, then another was added, now a third has been added. All in the same solution but as different projects, creating a launcher was meant to simplify things. Basically the 3 apps require different data, I have to be vague since its a business app but they're all along the same vein of what they do, but they serve very different purposes

Comment: @Thespragg ah ok in that case you need to ensure that any call to the resources are fully qualified using the projects own namespace. It's possible the run-time is getting confused.

Comment: @Digitalsa1nt So I need to move the resources to the launcher?

Comment: @Thespragg that would be one option. It's tricky to make an appropriate suggestion without having more info on the solution set up. But I suspect that when the individual apps call resources they are looking at the resources associated with the launching apps namespace rather than their own.

Comment: Just restating what I understood, please correct me if I am wrong. You have 3 separate WPF apps and you are writing another one (launcher). Data for all 3 WPF apps are loaded  in launcher and the user clicks on any of the app icon to open that app with data. Correct?

Comment: @GauravMathur Almost, I'll simplify the "data" part, each of the 3 apps has it's own page within the launcher, when the user chooses a page it gets populated with a DataGrid containing the "save files" for that app, they choose a save file which then launches the selected app with that save file

Comment: @Thespragg `save files` are those real files and do you have a path to them? If so, you could just launch the 3 other apps and pass the file(s) as a command line argument.

Comment: @Matthiee The files are served by an api

Comment: As what @Matthiee mentioned, that's what I was trying to figure out. If you do not have to/fro communication with launcher and 3 WPF apps. You can pass the file path and if you do not have a file path you can still pass the data as command line parameter.

Comment: I think I'm, just going to make seperate launchers for each, the codebase is too big to pull apart, especially since it's written in a way that making changes to anything within the first of the 3 apps would cause it to break previously saved data

Comment: @Thespragg can you update your question and show some example of what `this.data` is.

Comment: @Matthiee it's a simplified way of showing I need to interact with variables and controls from the second app, as I said above I'm giving up on this since I wasn't the one that wrote the first app and it's too tightly coupled to make changes to, I'd need to be able to make the launcher without modifying the code for that project at all since it's really not worth me spending the time to repair that app if I have to change the way the data is loaded